# Overloading two functions with object and list<object> parameter

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log("Test");//Call Log(object obj)
        Log(new List<string>{"Test","Test2"});;//Also Call Log(object obj)
    }

    public static void Log(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }

    public static void Log(List<object> objects)
    {
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }
```

In first line i call log with a string value and it invokes `Log(object obj)` but in the second line i call `Log` with list of string `new List<string>{"Test","Test2"}` but compiler invoke `Log(object obj)` instead of `Log(List<object> objects)`.

**Why compiler has this behavior?**

How can i call the second log with list of string?

Comment: You can pass list of objects which contains strings `Log(new List<object>{"Test","Test2"})`

Comment: You know that `List<object>` and `List<string>` are different types right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A `List<string>` ***is not*** a `List<object>`; however, `List<string>` ***is*** an `object` - so it makes perfect sense to choose that overload. Try instead:

```
public static void Log<T>(IList<T> objects)
{
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

or even:

```
public static void Log<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

You might also like:

```
public static void Log(params object[] objects)
{
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

which can be used as:

```
Log("Test","Test2");
```

Comment: You know the reason, and I know the reason, that `List<string>` is not a `List<object>` but I bet the OP does not know why, I think a link explaining why (possibly to another SO question on covariance) would be quite helpful.

Comment: There's no reason for the function to be generic - while List<string> can't be cast to List<object>, it can be cast to IEnumerable<object> [and to IEnumerable, which List<int> can be cast to]

Answer (score 7):

A variation on Marc Gravell's answer:

```
public static void Log(IReadOnlyList<object> objects)
{
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

This doesn't add anything to this particular example, but if you wanted to use indexed access to the collection like you could with a `List<T>`, this lets you do that in a way that `IEnumerable<object>` doesn't. (And yes, there's a LINQ operator for indexed access of enumerables, but it's clumsy, and may also be horribly slow. `IReadOnlyList<object>` is useful if you want to make it clear that your method requires efficient indexed access.)

Like Marc's version that uses `IEnumerable<object`> as the argument type, this exploits covariance - unlike `List<T>`, `T` is covariant in `IEnumerable<T>` and in `IReadOnlyList<T>`. That means that because `string` is an `object`, an `IEnumerable<string>` is an `IEnumerable<object>`, and likewise, `IReadOnlyList<string>` is an `IReadOnlyList<object>`.

The read-only nature of both interfaces is important. The whole reason your original example fails is that `List<T>` supports both reading and writing - if you pass me a `List<object>` I can add anything to it - a `string`, a `Giraffe` or whatever I like. That's why a `List<string>` is not an acceptable substitute for a `List<object>` - I can't add a `Giraffe` to a `List<string>`, even though I can add one to a `List<object>`. But because `IEnumerable<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` do not allow objects to be added to the collections they represent, all that matter is what you can get out, not what you can put in. Anything that comes out of a collection that contains only `string` objects will be an `object` because everything's an `object`.

And yes, I know your original code didn't attempt to add anything to the list, but that doesn't matter - all C# cares about in this case is how the function signature looks. And by specifying `IReadOnlyList<object>` you are making clear that you will never attempt to modify the list, at which point C# knows it's OK to pass the `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

`List<string>` cannot be cast to `List<Object>`.
If you have a `List<Object>` you can add objects of any kind to it.
If you have a `List<String>`, you can only add strings to it.
Therefore, a `List<String>` cannot be cast to `List<Object>`, because it can't be used the same way.

Comment: An interesting side-note on variance, though: a `string[]` has the same features vs `object[]` - but a `string[]` ***can*** be cast to an `object[]`. If you push a non-`string` value in via the indexer, it errors at runtime (`ArrayTypeMismatchException`). But it lets you do it at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a good example of [Liskov Substitution Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). LSP in its simple explanation claims that if an animal can bite, then a dog (who is an animal) should be able to bite too.

It's like syllogism in logic, which states that:

1. All animals eat
2. Cow is an animal
3. Thus cow eats

I think here, compiler follows this principal, because:

1. All objects can be logged (`public void Log (object obj) {}`)
2. `List<string>` is an object
3. Thus `List<string>` can be used as a parameter of that method, and be logged.

Comment: This explains why the `object` overload *is* valid, but not why it's "better" than the `List` overload, according to the compiler.

Comment: And nobody wanted to explain "why". Did I anywhere said it's "better"?

Comment: No, you didn't, which is the *problem*.  In this case, the `List` overload *isn't a valid overload*.  For that reason, the compiler rejects it as an option and uses the `object` overload as the "better" overload through its overload resolution.  There are several steps which include determining which overloads are valid, picking the "best" among those, and then continuing compilation with that overload.  You stopped half way through step one.  Your analysis is incomplete, even though it is not incorrect.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati : +1, :-) __BUT__ is this answer pointing to __---------->__